# file_get_contents(includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' )); not working

Tags: php

Hello I want to get the contents from the local jquery path in my wordpress theme. I am doing the following code:

`$jq = file_get_contents(includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' ));`

when I echo out the variable `jq` there is nothing stored in it

`echo $mergedJs; // nothing`

This only happens when I upload the theme to the server,it works fine on my local which is odd.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out, i had to change

`$jq = file_get_contents(includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' ));`

to

`$jq = file_get_contents(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/js/jquery/jquery.js');`

and it worked. can anyone explain why this works and the old one doesnt?

thanks!

Comment: Depending on your PHP configuration `file_get_contents()` cannot be used on URLs. PHP needs `allow_url_fopen` to be true for that to work. It would be much slower anyway, because you'd be wasting time making an HTTP request to the same server. Using the path is the better option.